# Unpredictable behavior of y-axis labels of Highchart

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

```
    Hope someone can explain the logic behind the following Highcharts behavior:
1. As seen in the jsFiddle, Y-axis label is till 25 though it can stop at 20 as the highest positive value  is 19.
2. I have used endOnTick:  which solved this problem but arises new one.
3. Again I used maxPadding and minPadding but it doesn't solve the issue for all the cases.
I am unable to understand the underlying logic. Can anyone please provide solution?
```

> https://jsfiddle.net/3rLd5guf/1/

> https://jsfiddle.net/3rLd5guf/2/

> https://jsfiddle.net/3rLd5guf/3/

As seen the yaxis tick should not stop at 10 since there are values above 10 for example may month

Comment: Please provide a link to the JsFiddle you are referring to.

Comment: @Mushroomator,plz chck now

Answer (score 0):

Use `maxPadding: 0` and don't disable `endOnTick` option. Without padding and with disabled `endOnTick`, `yAxis.max` is calculated as 19 and that's why it is not showed.

```
  yAxis: [{
    maxPadding: 0,
    ...
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k7420gjL/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.maxPadding

Comment: Thank you ppotaczek. May I know how is the value 19 calculated ? And also in the below fiddle I want the yaxis to go till 30 or 25 as the maximum value is 20 and looks like it's out of graph view. https://jsfiddle.net/jcvsLk5m/

Comment: Hi @Haswika, The value 19 is just the highest value in your data, so without any padding and rounding tick values (caused by `endOnTick: false`), it is just set as `yAxis.max`. For more information, you can check Highcharts source code: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/bc78a5fbee7507342a47fc20f03ec1d442d4fe77/ts/Core/Axis/Axis.ts#L1927

Comment: If you want to have `30` as the maximum value, just stay with default `maxPadding`: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xd7mkjL8/ For a bigger customization, you can use: `tickPositioner` function: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositioner